# Get properties of a JSON object streamed as NDJSON using fetch

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, ndjson

I am trying to get NDJSON data from an API using fetch. Since I only need one JSON object, I would like to do this using fetch. The data provided by the API is in the form (formatting by me, actual response is a single line):

```
{
  "a": "value",
  "b": "value",
  "c": "value",
  "d": "value",
  "e": "value"
}
```

When I simply log the data, everything works fine and I get the above response as an object:

```
const obj = await fetch(url, {
  method: "GET"
}).then(res => res.json());
console.log(obj);
```

But when I try to log one of the properties of that object, nothing gets logged (no errors):

```
const obj = await fetch(url, {
  method: "GET"
}).then(res => res.json());
console.log(obj.a);
```

Even logging `JSON.stringify(obj)` does not work. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Hey Wais - when you say `ndjson` you mean the endpoint responds with a number of these objects one per line, right?

Comment: Yes. The API has an option for the number of items to request. In my case I am only requesting one item.

Comment: Can you try this: `scramjet.StringStream.from(() => fetch(url).then(res => res.body)).JSONParse().each(console.log).catch(console.error)` - you'd need to install `scramjet` and require it.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for a way to do it using fetch.

Comment: I understand that, I'll propose a way without additional deps - I just need to know what's the issue there to offer an answer. :)

Comment: The issue is that whenever I log a property or write it to a file, nothing is logged/written.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233008/discussion-between-michal-karpacki-and-wais-kamal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to drill down into what happened and point out couple problems you encountered - which probably made the whole thing much harder to solve than it should be.

1. I suspect that the API kept sending more than one line of data regardless of what you told,
2. ndjson is not a standard JSON string and fails,
3. Promises in node tend to fail silently if you don't add proper handling.

The three issues caused the result to be `<nothing>` while it should be an error explaining that the file cannot be parsed.

The solution I offered was to use fetch with `scramjet` like this:

```js
const {StringSteram} = require("scramjet");

const stream = StringStream
  .from(async () => (await fetch(url)).body)
  .JSONParse()
;
```

StringStream.from accepts a stream or a method that returns one, and then the magic happens in JSONParse

- the method takes every line apart
- then parses that line as json

So now `stream` is a flowing list of objects. In node >= 12 you can simply iterate over it in a loop:

```js
for await (const item of stream) {
   console.log(item);
}
```

And since the resulting stream class has some creature comfort functions if you just want the data as an `Array`:

```js
console.log(await stream.toArray());
```

You don't have to use scramjet and you can work it out with just existing modules like this:

```
const { createInterface } = require("readline");
const { PassThrough } = require("stream");

const input = (await fetch(url)).body;
const output = new PassThrough();
createInterface({ input, output });

for await (const line of output) {
   console.log(JSON.parse(line));
}
```

Both solutions will take you there - with `scramjet` you can add more processing to the stream like: `stream.filter(item => checkValid(item))` or whatever you may need, but in the end the goal can be reached either way.

Comment: Well laid out! But I am absolutely sure I am only getting one JSON object, because I can see the response when I type in the URL in the browser. Thank you, this helped.

Comment: Perhaps there's some residue, like a trailing line?

Comment: Yes there is actually, but does that make a difference? It should still be valid JSON.

Comment: Not if that's just whitespace. If there are any non-whitespace characters then that would solve it, otherwise it should work with Scramjet as well as with just normal Fetch API `body.json()`.

Comment: I mean it's quite easy to say: found a solution, dunno why it works but it does. I'd take a  look at the exact response, maybe even by dumping the response with `curl` and checking exactly what the API returns character by character. I mean it should just work as in your question, so this is a bit of a mistery - all scramjet does is splitting that response line by line.

Comment: There is a carriage return character followed by a newline character at the end of the NDJSON file, but nevertheless `JSON.parse("[]\r\n")` works correctly.

Comment: That's true... I don't think then that the issue is in the server indeed. I'm not sure how this makes a difference. I'm happy it did though. :)